# Xamarin IOS Linker Error when adding project

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-linker

So I just added a utility project to my Xamarin solution and now I am getting linker errors. This doesn't make sense because I have Linker Behavior set to don't link. Does anyone know if there is a way to get around this?

[image]

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): error : framework not found Carbon
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System.Net.Security' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'Kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'libEGL' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'ole32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'gdi32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'comdlg32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'winspool' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'user32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'shell32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'oleaut32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'gdiplus' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'gdi32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'user32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'libX11' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'libcups' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): warning MT5215: References to 'gdiplus' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(885,3): error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Comment: What is `gdiplus` ?

Comment: I believe that is something that syncfusion uses

Comment: If so, maybe ask them why `gdiplus`, `gdi32`, `libX11` are included, maybe you added something that imported things like `libX11` into your project, and X11 is not an iOS and just will not work (nor "gdi" under the normal context of what GDI is)